# Need help implementing functions in GroceryItem class

Tags: c++, function, class, parameter-passing

Hello I've ran into some trouble creating a GroceryItem class and using functions to accept and set input from a user.

Currently when I run the dataEntry function, the compiler moves on to the next function before accepting input from the first function.

I've created a test milk object to test my code but It doesn't allow me to enter data before moving to the next input prompt.

Once I can figure out the class functions, I will also create an array of objects and input values for such.

Any advice for how I can go about fixing this class and functions would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class GroceryItem{
private: int stockNumber;
         double price = 0.0;
         int quantity;
         double totalValue;
         double setPrice();
         int setStockNum();
         int setQuantity();
         void setTotalValue();
public:
    void dataEntry();
    void displayValues();

};
int GroceryItem::setStockNum(){
    int stock = 0;
cout << "Enter the stock number for the grocery item: ";

do {
    cout << "Stock Number(1000-9999): ";
    cin >> stock;
} while (!(stock >= 1000 && stock <= 9999));

    stockNumber = stock;
    return stockNumber;
}
double GroceryItem::setPrice(){
    double x = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter the price of the item: ";
    while (!(x > 0))    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive number for price!";
        cin >> x;
    }
    price = x;
    return price;
}
int GroceryItem::setQuantity(){
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Enter the quantity in stock: ";
    while (!(x > 0)){
        cout << "Please enter a positive number for quantity!";
        cin >> x;
    }
    quantity = x;
    return quantity;
}
void GroceryItem::setTotalValue(){
    totalValue = (quantity * price);
}
void GroceryItem::dataEntry(){
    setStockNum();
    system("pause");
    setPrice();
    system("pause");
    setQuantity();
    system("pause");
    setTotalValue();
}
void GroceryItem::displayValues(){
    cout << "Stock number: " << stockNumber;
    cout << "\nItem price: " << price;
    cout << "\nQuantity on hand: " << quantity;
    cout << "\nTotal value of item: " << totalValue;
}


int main(){
    GroceryItem Milk;
    Milk.dataEntry();
    Milk.displayValues();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's not a valid line of code so not sure what you mean

Comment: You should initialize the `price` member using a constructor.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for using a *debugger*.

Comment: When you write code, start with something simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step; **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

Dude, pay attention to the condition of the while statement, the line

```
!(stock >= 1000 || stock <= 9999)
```

returns true for stock = 0 (always true, in this case), so the program won't enter the loop.
Maybe you meant something like:

```
!(stock >= 1000 && stock <= 9999)
```

AND(&&) not OR(||)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and that was changed, thanks. Also my loop was incorrect so I changed it to a do-while loop and now it works perfectly. I just have to use a do-while for my other inputs as well to only accept positive values